# A question about a form that is related to modular form

Tags: modular-forms

According to wikipedia

"A modular form of weight $k$ for the modular group
$SL(2, \mathbf Z)$ is a complex-valued function $f$ on the upper half-plane $H = {z ∈ C, Im(z) > 0}$, satisfying the following three conditions:

(1) $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $H$.

(2) $$f(-1/z) = z^k f(z)\tag{2A},$$
and
$$f(z+1) = f(z)\tag{2B}$$.

(3) $f(z)$ is required to be holomorphic as z → i∞.

Question: If only condition (2B) is not satisfied,but (1),(2A),(3) are still satisfied, what is the name of this form/function $f(z)$?

Comment: Isn't such a function just a periodic function?

Comment: No. Because the periodic condition (2B) is specifically dropped out from the requirement.  So $f(z)$ can be non-periodic.

Comment: Oops! I messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $B=2$ ....

The space of holomorphic function on the upper halfplane which are holomorphic at $\infty$ and satisfying $f(z+1)=f(z)$ is isomorphic to the space of holomorphic function on the open unit disc $D$.

This is so because there's a biholomorphic isomorphism ${\cal H}/{\Bbb Z}\simeq D\setminus\{0\}$ and the condition for $f$ to be holomorphic at $\infty$ is exactly that assuring that the corresponding function extends holomorphically to $0$.

---

If, instead, $f(z+1)=f(z)$ is the dropped relation, note that $z\mapsto-\frac1z$ is an involution of $\cal H$ with $z=i$ as unique fixed point. The shape of the functional equation tells immediately that $k$ must be even (for $f$ to be non-trivial) and the holomorphic functions are in one-to-one correspondence with the holomorphic functions on the quotient space $\cal H/\sim$ with the extra condition that they must vanish at $\bar\imath$ if $k\equiv2\bmod4$.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry for the confusion. (B) means condition (B) in (2).  Now I changed it to (2B) to be more specific.

Comment: @mike: I added some considerations for the "other" case (the one you meant). I don't think these functions have a specific name, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Andrea Thanks again!